# How can we get this tricky sum of included and excluded elements?

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose that we have $n$ elements.  Of these we pick $a$ elements that we must have, and $b$ elements that we must not have.  Now, if we have a set of $m$ of the $n$ elements, we can follow the rules just prescribed.  We must have the $a$ elements that we picked, and must not have the $b$ elements that we reject.  **How many different ways can we pick a set of $m$ of the $n$ elements that follow these rules?**

Comment: Just forget about the elements you absolutely want to exclude from your pick. It happens I've got $m$ elements here that you didn't know about, so I'm quite sure they will get excluded in whatever you pick.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen:  I set myself up for that one, didn't I?  I'm trying to get an answer for this for an algorithm (that you probably didn't know about) that I'm working on.  I hope the wording is at least ok.  Really, I group elements of this problem together by size.  I'm trying to find ways of getting different values for each group, so I thought of excluding elements.  I hope this problem isn't too tough. I'm starting to think that maybe I can re-express it in terms of multinomials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $\displaystyle \binom{n-a-b}{m-a}$.

There are $n-a-b$ elements that you neither auto-accept nor auto-reject. After the $a$ auto-accepted elements, you have room for $m-a$ more. Hence the binomial coefficient above.

Comment: I think I worded this question poorly, but your answer got me in the right direction.  Here's my thinking right now.  I want to find how many ways we can pick the set of $m$ elements.  So first I eliminate the auto-rejections from the equation; there are $\binom{n}{b}$ ways to do this.  Then I pick the auto-accepting elements.  There are $\binom{n-b}{a}$ ways to do this from what remains.  Finally, I use your formula to pick a set that works from this.  This all gives $\binom{n}{b} \binom{n-b}{a} \binom{n-a-b}{m-a}$.  This seems to work when I try with examples.  Does this make sense to you?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then yes, this is correct. This is also equal to the multinomial coefficient $\binom n{a,b,m-a,n-b-m}$.

Comment: I guess I should have worded in there that I was also looking for the formulas for picking $a$ and $b$.  I had a hunch that this could be done with a multinomial.  Many thanks, +1, and accepted!

Comment: Thanks :) I guess in hindsight it's easy to see why this is a multinomial. You're splitting the $n$ objects into four sets: the auto-accepts, the auto-rejects, the maybes that got accepted, and the maybes that got rejected.